# Logical AND operator with a condition

Tags: c++, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Given a threshold value T and a set of bitmaps, I want to create a resultant bitmap "br" such that the i'th bit of "br" is set to 1 only if the i'th bit is set to 1 in >=T bitmaps.

I will try to illustrate my question with an example: 
Let us assume that we have 4 bitmaps (of equi-length) and T=3:

```
b1 (10000)
b2 (01110)
b3 (10110)
b4 (00010)
```

Then my resultant bitmap br = (00010) - because only the 4th bit is set to 1 in >=3 bitmaps. If T=2, then br = (10110).

One naive way to do this would be to iterate through each bitmap and keep a vector that stores the count of bit 'i' in the i'th index. After that, one can iterate through this "count" vector.

Another way (I think) would be to implement a modified logical AND operator such that, in the resultant bitmap, the ith bit is set to 1 if it is set to 1 in >=T positions.

Is there any other efficient way to do this? I am using C++ and the EWAHBoolArray (https://github.com/lemire/EWAHBoolArray) library. Currently, they do not have the capability to do an AND operation between multiple bitmaps. 
Any response is much appreciated!

Comment: You could have several bitmaps D, such that Dj is the jth digit of the sum of the bitmaps B (that is, the ith bit of Dj is the jth digit of the binary number which is the number of bitmaps (of the set B) which have a 1 in position i). In your example, they would be {(01010) (10110) (00000)}.

Comment: A terrible question, please read about [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with some bit twiddling and addition. You're really trying to get the sum of individual bits. In order to do that with normal addition, you need to make room for the maximum sum that you can get for each column. You do that by splitting each value into 3 parts with masking. Then you add a constant that ensures your desired sum sets the upper bit, which you can then mask back off.

```
b1a = b1 & 0b01001;
b1b = (b1 >> 1) & 0b01001;
b1c = (b1 >> 2) & 0b01001;
b2a = b2 & 0b01001;
...
bra = ((b1a + b2a + b3a + b4a + 0b01001) & 0b100100) >> 2;
brb = ((b1b + b2b + b3b + b4b + 0b01001) & 0b100100) >> 1;
brc = ((b1c + b2c + b3c + b4c + 0b01001) & 0b100100);
br = bra | brb | brc;
```